# Rewriterule moved permanently from an old forum to new forum

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there a way to put a small rewriterule in .htaccess to redirect over 20.000 links from an old phpBB based forum to a new phpBB forum?
The old link is like this :

```
https://example.com/t123456-some-title
```

The new link is like this :

```
https://example.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=123456
```

`t-123456` is a variable number for topic number in the old forum, and the number is the same but with `viewtopic.php?t=123456`

I think that is possible with some regex, but I don't know how to make this.

Maybe something like :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^t-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /forum/viewtopic.php?t=$2 [R,L]
```

Big thanks to @MrWhite, the rewriterule work perfectly.

```
RewriteRule ^t(\d+) /forum/viewtopic.php?t=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: In your example URL you used `t123456`, but you later reference this with a hyphen, ie. `t-123456`?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, the old URL is like t123456 without the hyphen and the new URL is like viewtopic.php?t=123456 with an equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^t-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /forum/viewtopic.php?t=$2 [R,L]
> ```

Almost, except that the `$2` backreference in the *substitution* string (referencing the 2nd capturing subgroup) would contain `some-title`, not `123456`.

You don't seem to have a need to capture the *title*, so you can remove the surrounding parenthesis from the second group. In fact, if you are discarding the *title* altogether then you perhaps don't need to match this at all, unless it would result in a conflict with other URLs? You are only interested in the *id*.

This should ultimately be a 301 (permanent) redirect, however, it is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect (the default). So change `R` to `R=301` once you have tested that it works as expected.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^t-(\d+) /forum/viewtopic.php?t=$1 [R=301,L]
```

This matches any URL that *starts* `/t-<number>` and redirects to `/forum/viewtopic.php?t=<number>`

> **UPDATE:** Sorry, I was mistaken, the old URL is like `t123456` without the hyphen

Then just remove the hyphen in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. `^t(\d+)`

Comment: So if I understand,
RewriteRule ^t(\d+) /forum/viewtopic.php?t=$1 [R=301,L]
should work, without the hyphen.

Comment: @relik Yes, if your old URLs are of the form `/t123456-some-title` (no hyphen before the _number_). This redirect needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file (order matters). Test with 302 (temporary) redirects and clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Ok, I'll test this week and I'll tell you if it works.
Thx MrWhite.

Comment: Big thanks to @MrWhite, the rewriterule work perfectly.

RewriteRule ^t(\d+) /forum/viewtopic.php?t=$1 [R=301,L]

I'll make some rewriterules for other links based on your tip. =)